# Is there a way to add standard error bars to geom lines in ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a follow up to a question answered previously here: [Plotting values in ggplot over time by group, with condition where one group is one line of the mean, and the other group as individual lines in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353999/plotting-values-in-ggplot-over-time-by-group-with-condition-where-one-group-is/66354741#66354741)

I have a dataset which I would like to add standard error bars for treatment rates at each year for each line. I would like to modify the code below to include " geom = "errorbar" before geom = "line" but get the following error: Error in stat_summary(data = ~subset(., Intervention == 0), aes(group = -1), : formal argument "geom" matched by multiple actual arguments.

Is there a different way to modify this? Thank you for your help in advance.

Sample data:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)

states <- rownames(USArrests)
intervened <- sample(states, 10)

df <- expand.grid(year = 2010:2015, state = states)
df$Intervention <- as.numeric(df$state %in% intervened)
df$rate <- cumsum(rnorm(nrow(df)))
head(df)
#>   year   state Intervention      rate
#> 1 2010 Alabama            0 -0.574740
#> 2 2011 Alabama            0 -1.121372
#> 3 2012 Alabama            0 -1.685824
#> 4 2013 Alabama            0 -2.575862
#> 5 2014 Alabama            0 -3.053054
#> 6 2015 Alabama            0 -4.051441
```

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = rate, group = state)) +
  geom_line(
    data = ~ subset(., Intervention == 1),
    aes(colour = state)
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    data = ~ subset(., Intervention == 0),
    aes(group = -1),
    fun.data = mean_se,
    geom = "line", size = 2
  )
```

Comment: Harder to help without sample of data like yours.

Comment: Please offer at least a reproducible sample of your data. The function `dput()` might help.
Regarding the error bars, what about the `geom_errorbar()` geom?

Comment: Thank you in advance, sample data added.

Comment: See edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354741/11374827